# Will the Invisible Divs have any load on the page

Tags: php, html

Actually, My Question is little bit different, so I could not find any answer of my question on google. Therefore, I have to come here to get the answer of my solution.
I want to know that If I have about 50 Divs on my web page, which are invisible and they have some text data in them, Will they have any Load on the web page?

Comment: what do you mean with "Load"?

Comment: The browser will parse the html, even if the divs are hidden. It will also check CSS rules. So, probably the answer is "yes" but depends on what do you mean by "load".

Comment: Yes that will have get counted under DOM element. But how much they will give load to your webpage is depend on it's content. It has nothing to deal with visibility mode.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are inclued in the html of the page, so will make your page heavier.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they will be loaded.Load your html page and then "View Source" .. in html code you will see your hidden divs.

Answer (score 1):

The server will have to send the HTML data to the user. Therefor it will have a certain load on the server. In the other hand, just DIV's haven't any complicated code in it, so it won't be an issue for most webservers.